# Equations of motion in general relativity: Einstein field equations vs geodesic equation

Tags: general-relativity, curvature, geodesics

It is said that the equations of motion of a theory are those whose solutions give the coordinates/trajectory of the system.

I was wondering ¿which is the correct equation of motion in the theory of general relativity?

The einstein field equations

$ R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2} Rg_{\mu\nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu\nu} = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu\nu} $

Or the geodesic equation ?

$ \frac{d^2x^{\alpha}}{d\lambda^2} + \Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu} \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\lambda} = 0 $

Both give the behaviour of objects along curved regions of spacetime so which one is the correct equation of motion of the theory?

Comment: The geodesic equation gives the 2. order derivative equations of motion for which the initial conditions are the 1. and 0. order derivatives, see [here](http://relativity.yukterez.net/) for some examples in different coordinates.

Comment: The correct equation for what? Both are correct, just they refer to different things. To define a classical field theory you need to set up the equations of motion (EoM) of the field and the EoM of matter interacting with the field. The Einstein field equations (EFE) are the EoM of the gravitational field, the geodesic equation describes the motion of free particles in curved spacetime. Your question is equivalent to asking whether the "correct equations" of electrodynamics are Maxwell equations or the Lorentz force equation.